# Rotation of iPad resets animation of views back to start

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiviewcontroller, rotation

When I rotate the iPad, all the animated components (e.g. views/buttons) will go back to their original position as to when it was first loaded. Is there any way to prevent this?

Here is how I animate object when I click an button e.g.

```
- (IBAction)button1Pressed:(id)sender{

    [UIView animateWithDuration:ANIMATION_SPEED
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations:(void (^)(void)) ^{
                         self.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
                         _button1.center = CGPointMake(73.01, 419.0);
                         _button2.center = CGPointMake(750.0, 419.0);
                         _button3.center = CGPointMake(850.0, 419.0);
                         _button4.center = CGPointMake(950.0, 419.0);

                         CGRect theFrame = _loginView.frame;
                         theFrame.size.width = 576.f;
                         _View1.frame = theFrame;
                         _View2.frame = CGRectMake(_button2.center.x + 44.0, _button2.center.y / 2 - 89.0, 0.0, 597.0);
                         _View3.frame = CGRectMake(_button3.center.x + 44.0, _button3.center.y / 2 - 89.0, 0.0, 597.0);
                         _4View.frame = CGRectMake(_button4.center.x + 44.0, _button4.center.y / 2 - 89.0, 0.0, 597.0);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
                     }];
}
```

I'm still quite new so all the details will be appreciated :)

Comment: Have you designed your view with interface builder and add constraints?

Comment: 'The selected views have no constraints. At build time explicit left, top, width, and height constraints will be generated for the view.' - should they have constraints? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to create constraints for the interface you want to animate. Then add reference to your header file for those constraints as for any view element.

[image]

When you want to animate a view, you now have to update its constraints and ask to layout the views.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                         animations:^{
                             //in this case, I add 44 to my button Y position, so it will goes down 44px 
                             buttonYConstraint.constant += 44;
                             [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                         }
]
//Now don't forget to update constraints
[self.view updateConstraints];
```

Answer (score 0):

Turning off auto layout located under the 'Interface builder document' fixed this in quick fashion :)